# can i use nodes in blender render engine and have it render in material shading mode

Tags: rendering, node-editor

i was trying to use nodes in blender render engine because i want also to use textures nodes, just so i can  make my personal textures.
And when i try to render in material viewport shading the object apears black, apperas to only be able to render in render viewport  shading.

can someone please help me.
it would be very cool

ty in advance.

// the uv's are setup//

[image: print screen]

Comment: You need some lighting, do you have any?

Comment: Have you any light in scene?